# Angular Rxjs: emit all merged observables with delay continuously with async pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, async-pipe

Hello guys I'm trying to use a data object in html file and i'm using the async pipe and a subject to emit id and get server response.
Here is my code:

```
     logDetails$: Observable<LogDetails>;
     getDetails$ = new Subject<string>();

     this.logDetails$ = this.getDetails$.pipe(
        map(id => ApiRoutes.fileLogDetailsApiRoute.replace(":id", id)),
        switchMap(apiRoute => this.http.get<LogDetails>(apiRoute))
    );
```

I use an async pipe in my view to use subscribe for result.

```
*ngIf="logDetails$ | async; let details"
```

Now i want this behaviour: I emit the **getDetails$** with id from multiple locations.
Then i need that before server call a **null** value for result get emmited to the view and then the server response **(LogDetails object)** after some delay.

1. send a default value for result
2. delay
3. send server response

Can i use operators to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `startWith` and `delay`.

```ts
this.logDetails$ = this.getDetails$.pipe(
  map(id => ApiRoutes.fileLogDetailsApiRoute.replace(":id", id)),
  switchMap(apiRoute => this.http.get<LogDetails>(apiRoute).pipe(
    delay(1000),
    startWith(null)
  )),
);
```

Comment: @fridoo You made my day! A question: when i use the **startWith** on **http.get** pipe it's working as expected, but when i move it to the first level pipe the first value is not get emitted. why? but others get.

Comment: @ArminTorkashvand The observable you in return in `switchMap` gets subscribed to when ever `getDetails$` emits. The outer observable gets subscribe to only once (I guess).

Comment: @fridoo That's true!